# texture paint window not showing image

Tags: interface

I am very new to Blender and for the first time in Blender I was using the texture paint tab.  I had a basic scene built in the geometry nodes tab and wanted to add some coloring.  I was able to change the color for one object and then did something and now I don't see any images in the texture paint tab but the image is still visible in the geometry nodes tab.

Comment: hello could you please show a screenshot of your whole interface?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to re-select your image in the UV Editor.

[image]